# IllegalStateException with Pattern/Matcher

Tags: java, regex

I'm using [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) to capture groups using a regular expression in Java and it keeps throwing an `IllegalStateException` even though I know that the expression matches.

This is my code:

```
String safeName = Pattern.compile("(\\.\\w+)$").matcher("google.ca").group();
```

I'm expecting `safeName` to be `.ca` as captured with the capturing group in the regular expression but instead I get:

> IllegalStateException: No match found

I also tried with `.group(0)` and `.group(1)` but the same error occurs.

According to the documentation for [`group()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group()) and `group(int group)`:

> Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one. Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression `m.group(0)` is equivalent to `m.group()`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First you need to call either `matches`, `find` or `lookingAt` methods to match an input against the patter, and then `group` can be used to obtain informations about previous match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Matcher` is helper class which handles iterating over data to search for substrings matching regex. It is possible that entire string will contain many sub-strings which can be matched, so by calling `group()` you can't specify which actual match you are interested in. To solve this problem Matcher lets you iterate over all matching sub-strings and then use parts you are interested in.

So before you can use `group` you need to let Matcher iterate over your string to `find()` match for your regex. To check if regex matches entire String we can use `matches()` method instead of `find()`.

Generally to find all matching substrings we are using

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compiler("yourPattern");
Matcher m = p.matcher("yourData");
while(m.find()){
    String match = m.group();
    //here we can do something with match... 
}
```

Since you are assuming that text you want to find exists only once in your string (at its end) you don't need to use loop, but simple `if` (or conditional operator) should solve your problem.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\.\\w+)$").matcher("google.ca");
String safeName = m.find() ? m.group() : null;
```